# Reset a Vue counter component from the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, gsap

I have a Vue counter which counts up from 1 to 10. It's implemented as a component. I need to reset the counter from the main app. What's the best way to do this? As you can see from my example, the watch method doesn't do the job:

```js
Vue.component('my-counter', {
  template: "#counter-vue",
  data: function() {
    return {
      age_now: null
    }
  },
  props: {
    age: Number
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.age_now = this.age;
    TweenLite.to(this, 10, { age_now: this.$root.age_end, roundProps: "age_now", ease:Linear.easeNone });
  },
  watch: {
    age(val) {
      this.age_now = val;
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    age: 1,
    age_end: 10
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.age = 1;
    } 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="counter-vue">
 <div>
  <p>Age: {{age_now}}</p>
 </div>
</script>
   
<div class="container">
   <h1>Vue Component Reset</h1>
  <my-counter :age="age"></my-counter>
  <button @click.prevent="reset">Reset</button>
    <p>What's the best way to implement the reset of the component to restart the count up from 1 to 10?</p>
</div>
```

See also on CodePen: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/OagMJy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your watcher for `age` in the `my-counter` component isn't ever firing because you aren't ever changing the value of the `age` prop. If it's initialized to `1` and gets set to `1` in the click-handler, it won't trigger the watcher because the value didn't change.

But second of all, it'd make more sense, in this case, to just move the `reset` method to the `my-counter` component and then call it from the parent scope via a `ref`, like so:

```
<my-counter ref="counter" :age="age"></my-counter>
<button @click.prevent="$refs.counter.reset">Reset</button>
```

It looks like you'll also need to call the `TweenLite.to` method again if you want the counter to increment again. So it'd be good to pull that logic into its own method (say `count`) that you can call from the `mounted` hook and from the `reset` method.

Also, I noticed that it also seems like the `TweenLite.to` method is overriding the binding for the `age` prop until the counter has finished incrementing. If you want to reset the counter before the `TweenLite.to` method has finished, you'll need to store a reference to the returned tween object and then call its `kill` method before the counter starts.

Finally, I'm seeing that you're referencing the `this.$root.age_end` in the object passed to the `TweenLite.to`. Except in rare cases, this is considered bad practice, as now the component unnecessarily depends on the root Vue instance always having an `age_end` property and it obscures the flow of data. Since that value appears to be static, you should just set it as a data property of the component. Or at least pass it in as a prop from the parent.

Here's a working example with my suggested changes:

```js
Vue.component('my-counter', {
  template: "#counter-vue",
  data: function() {
    return {
      age_now: null,
      age_end: 10,
      tween: null,
    }
  },
  props: {
    age: Number
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.age_now = this.age;
    this.count();
  },
  methods: {
    count() {
      if (this.tween) {
        this.tween.kill();
      }
    
      this.tween = TweenLite.to(this, 10, { 
        age_now: this.age_end, 
        roundProps: "age_now", 
        ease: Linear.easeNone 
      });
    },
    reset() {
      this.age_now = 1;
      this.count();
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    age: 1,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="counter-vue">
  <div>
    <p>Age: {{age_now}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
   
<div class="container">
  <h1>Vue Component Reset</h1>
  <my-counter ref="counter" :age="age"></my-counter>
  <button @click.prevent="$refs.counter.reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an event bus, bind the reset to the event and then emit the event on click of the button, but that's a bit of an overkill in this case

Comment: Very clear and helpful, thanks. I am incorporating it into my code now.

Comment: Hmm. Seems the restructured Tween now kills the enter-active CSS transition on the component. I'll post a separate question if I can't sort it out.